# Wireless keeps on disconnecting 14.04 . Any different solutions?

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, disconnect

I do know that this question have been asked plenty of times and I did read and did most of the solutions people recommended. Unfortunately, couldnt found any solution yet.

Basicly, Internet drops every 5 mins and once I reconnect, everything works fine again. This occurs in every different wireless network.

I would love to hear if someone has a solution

Note: Im a new Ubuntu user ! And this is my first question on forums. Please forgive me if I broke any forum rules or asked my question unclear.